# Im trying to write code to get (doc id) from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Look at my database structure:

[image]

and here is my code that I want to use ID in :

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        child: Dismissible(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
          background: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.delete),
                Text(
                  'Move to trash',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Righteous',
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
            return await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Delete Confirmation"),
                    content: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this item?"),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                          child: const Text("Delete")),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                        child: const Text("Cancel"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
          onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) async {
            if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
              print('item deleted');
            }
            await deleteCar(
                'wam4jSgeIpWHIBLVXvmv'); //I want to get doc ID to delete it
          },
```

Comment: bro I just want one line like : FirebaseFirestore.instance.coll... To get the ID 
I searched before ask this question but I dont find solution 
anyway, thank you bro

Comment: That's called a `documentId` and all documents you read in have a `documentId` property. Can you include the code you use to read in the Firestore data, and then indicate where the trouble is? That will give us a better idea of how the documents are handled and maybe point you in the right direction. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

There is some way:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('$YOUR_COLLECTION')
.where('uid',  isEqualTo: "$UID_OF_THAT_ITEM").limit(1).get().then((value) => value.docs.first.id);
```

As you get it value.docs.first.id is what you need.

Comment: thanks bro but its not working with me 
I wnat it to get ID value as  a String to call is in delete method deleteCar('String')

Comment: Dude, actually you don’t need to define id to delete doc. You are already selecting it after value.docs.first. My suggestion is calling smth delete like method on this selection(I din’t remember exactly remove or delete…)

Comment: yeah brother your code work perfect with me I just add another where() with the name of the car to get specific card.
Thank you for helping me, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you triying to achieve. But the way I see it, you can duplicate that id as an atribute of the element when you create it for example.

```
"aasdasd" :{
"id": "aasdasd",
"carName": "car", 
}
```

or when you map cars, use the key you got as an atribute of your Car Model. This is an example for products.

```
  static Future loadProducts() async {
    final url = Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'products.json');
    final res = await http.get(url);
    final Map<String, dynamic> productsMap = json.decode(res.body);
    final List<Product> products = productsMap.keys
        .map((key) => Product(
              id: key,
              name: productsMap[key]['name'],
              description: productsMap[key]['description'],
              price: productsMap[key]['price'],
              imagen: productsMap[key]['imagen'],
              isAvailable: productsMap[key]['isAvailable'],
            ))
        .toList();

    return products;
  }
```

'key' is the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

this line solve the problem :

```
String gg = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('carsData')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: loggedInUser.uid)
      .where('CarName', isEqualTo: nameCar)
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.docs.first.id);
```

but when you have 2 items have the same CarName you must add another where() to get specific id.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('carsData')
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: 'selected_car_uid')
            .get()
            .then((value) {
          value.docs.forEach((element) {
            print(element.id); // you will get your firestore id and then delete via this id.

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("carsData")
            
            .doc(element.id)
             
            .delete()
            .then((value_2) {
          print('========> successfully deleted');
        });

          });
        });
```

HAPPY CODING :)